# Onedrive file picker issue

Tags: onedrive, filepicker

I've setup an API account for onedrive file upload and select uploaded files via the file picker.

But` it is showing a message "This file couldn't be shared. Please try again later."

```js
`var odOptions = {
 clientId: APP CLIENT ID,
 action: download,
 advanced: {
  redirectUri: redirect url according to app redirect url
 },
 multiSelect: false,
 openInNewWindow: true,
 success: function(files) { 
 },
 cancel: function() {  },
 error: function() {  }
}`
```

https://snag.gy/EeqabQ.jpg

Even clicking on Cancel button the same message shows.  How this issue can be fixed?

Comment: Please use the Image toolbar button to include images in your post, instead of hosting them on an off-site location. It's pretty difficult to tell you why a specific file can't be shared, because we have no information related to that file.

Comment: it is not letting me to upload an image. it is showing i need 10 points to insert an image.

Comment: I can't help you, because you've posted a link to a .jpg, and only .png images are accepted here.

Comment: Not hard to get 10 points. Start by taking the tour. If I remember correct you get some points for that.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same error message. In my case an old version of Safari wasn't compatible with the picker. Upgrading to Safari 10.1.2 solved the issue and the error message disappeared.